# Validar reCaptcha v2 después de pasar un tiempo

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, captcha

y tengo que validar esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Esto ocurre pasados de unos segundos después de haberlo activado, cuando se activa le pongo una clase a un label, pero cuando se desactiva solo no se le quita la clase al label.

```
  function callback_error_aliado(){
  $(".purpleButton_aliados").addClass("sinElegir");
  $(".purpleButton_aliados").removeClass("conElegir");
}

function callback_ready_aliado(){
  $(".purpleButton_aliados").removeClass("sinElegir");
  $(".purpleButton_aliados").addClass("conElegir");

}
```

Con esta función se cuando lo activan y cuando lo desactivan

Este es el captcha:

```
<label class="purpleButton_aliados">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mycLAVE" data-callback='callback_ready_aliado' data-error-callback='callback_error_aliado'></div>
        </label>
```